# Simple Rewrite not working

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've been staring at this for far too long. To cope with a Wordpress URL structure change, I need a URL rewrite to cope with old links that are floating around the net. The rule I've created is

```
RewriteRule [0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

To match posts with URLs like

```
/2013/02/05/Some-wonderful-article
```

supposedly redirecting to

```
/Some-wonderful-article
```

Apache seems to be ignoring this, though, and happily sticks with the original URL. Can anyone see why? Am I forgetting some quirk of Apache's implementation of regex? I've already wasted some time playing with \d instead of [0-9] ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I added the command to activate the rewrite engine and also a line which defines a base for the RewriteRules.